# Java String index out of bounds with text file input

Tags: java, indexing

I am trying to split a `String` input into two using the following code:

```
public TypeValue(String line) {
    while (line.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    type = line.substring(0,i);
    value = line.substring(i);
}
```

my input is a textfile that looks like this:

```
10 16
10 32
10 9024720
F 10
F 1
F 111111
F 100000
F 10110110100111001
```

However, I always get a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13`. This only happens when I try to read the input from a text file. When I use the terminal to input the lines one by one it works just fine.

I have been looking for a couple hours but I cannot figure out what is causing this. It is also always "`13`", even when I delete all but the first line from the text file. Can anybody help me with this?

Edit: Thank you for the help everybody. The problem was with something else entirely. I didn't properly put my File in the Scanner in my main method...

Comment: `line.charAt(i) != ' '` this fails for some `line` (when line.length <= 13) when `i` = 13. It is likely that one of the lines does not have a trailing space. Also, I suspect that it is likely that `i` is never 'reset' correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. In a couple of tries I resetted i but still didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply use [`line.split(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which will return an array of `String`, then get either the first or the second value using respectively the index `0` and `1` of the resulting array as next:

```
String[] values = line.split(" ");
type = values[0];
value = values[1];
```

Another way could be to use [`line.indexOf(' ')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) to get the index of the space character in your `String`.

```
int index = line.indexOf(' ');
// From 0 to the index where we found the space
type = line.substring(0, index);
// Starts from index + 1 to skip the space
value = line.substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. My output isn't correct anymore though. It seems as if the input that is read from the textfile is just completely different when I just use the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize `i`. Try this:

```
public TypeValue(String line) {
    int i=0;
    while (line.charAt(i) != ' ') {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    type = line.substring(0,i);
    value = line.substring(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing raw ascii values than characters,
as in

```
public TypeValue(String line) {
    int i=0;
    //ascii value for space is 32
    while ((int)line.charAt(i) != 32) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    type = line.substring(0,i);
    value = line.substring(i);
}
```

Comment: ' ' is far more understandable than 32. And, `charAt` returns a UTF-16 code unit (`char`), not ASCII.